# Javascript- if statement in Chrome keepvid script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Sorry if this is stupidly easy, but I don't even program in java.

There's keepvid.com, and they have nice script to get downloads from youtube.
Code:

```
javascript:(
    function(){

        window.open('http://keepvid.com/?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'')
    }
)();
```

I managed to tinker with it so it takes me directly to mp3 download (adding '&mode=mp3'), but it didn't work with long url's with playlists and stuff, so I made one which cuts it off. Code:

```
javascript:(
    function(){

        var url=location.href;
        url=url.substring(0, url.indexOf('&'));
        window.open('http://keepvid.com/?url='+encodeURIComponent(url)+'&mode=mp3')
    }
)();
```

Ultimately I want it to work in all cases, but if url is clean it pastes '&', I tried using IF and it works for manually written true/false, but I cant get it to work with .contains. Code:

```
javascript:(
    function(){

        var url=location.href;
        if(url.contains('&')){

            url=url.substring(0, url.indexOf('&'));
        };
        window.open(

        'http://keepvid.com/?url='+encodeURIComponent(url)+'&mode=mp3'
        )
    }
)();
```

Comment: Java is not Javascript

Comment: as mentioned, I'm not programming in java, tbh it's my first time seeing this, if it's offensive to anyone I'm sincerely sorry

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if url contains '&' as condition I set

```
if(url.indexOf('&')!=-1)
```

which states 'if index of "&" is not -1' (I guess -1 is value for not found)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you looked at the console. If you had, you would have seen an error such as "undefined is not a function", on the line where you call `contains`. `contains` is undefined because there is no method `contains` on strings.

There was a Firefox-specific `String#contains` which was changed to `includes` to match the ES6 spec. Some libraries may provide their own `contains` method on strings.

You will find `includes` in few if any browsers as of yet. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes. See also http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#String.prototype.contains. You can find a polyfill, which looks slightly over-engineered to me, at https://github.com/mathiasbynens/String.prototype.includes.